# How to declare that a button has been clicked outside the onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var status = 'not active';
    $('#button').on('click', function() {
                var button = 'THE BUTTON IS CLICKED';
                var status = 'active';
                alert(button);
     });
      if(status == 'active'){
          alert('THE BUTTON IS ACTIVATED');
      } else {
          alert('THE BUTTON IS NOT ACTIVE');
      }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">X</button>
```

In my code here, I'm trying to get the `status` of the button out side of the onclick function to enter the `if statement` but it doesn't get defined outside the function at all. i want to get the `alert('THE BUTTON IS ACTIVATED');` working.

Comment: use global scopes like window.status :-)

Comment: @Mohsen Can you please put it in answer built on my example? Because it's the first time i hear about the global scopes.

Comment: check this dear Calibur :-) https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring a new variable also called `status`, which "obfuscates" the external `status`, inside the function. Just remove the `var` to use the external one:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var status = 'not active';
    $('#button').on('click', function() {
                var button = 'THE BUTTON IS CLICKED';
                status = 'active';
                alert(button);
     });
      if(status == 'active'){
          alert('THE BUTTON IS ACTIVATED')
      } else {
          alert('THE BUTTON IS NOT ACTIVE');
      }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">X</button>
```

**EDIT**: There are two weird things on your code: you use the status, for the alert, only once, when the document is ready, and you don't switch the `active` status. Maybe you want something like this (would be better using boolean variable instead of string for this status):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var status = 'not active';
    $('#button').on('click', function() {
                var button = 'THE BUTTON IS CLICKED';
                status = (status == 'active') ? 'not active' : 'active';
                alert(button);

                showButtonStatus();
     });

     function showButtonStatus() {
        if(status == 'active'){
          alert('THE BUTTON IS ACTIVATED')
        } else {
          alert('THE BUTTON IS NOT ACTIVE');
        }
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">X</button>
```

Comment: I was in the middle of writing this :P

Comment: But the `alert('THE BUTTON IS ACTIVATED');` still didn't work.

Comment: When I click the button, it alerts that he button is activated. Is this not the expected behavior? Otherwise I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, as your code sample seems to work.

Comment: This still won't work as the `if` is only executed once on load, before the button can ever be clicked. How this has 2 upvotes I don't even know

Comment: @Kevin When you click the button, It shows you `alert(button);` which is inside the `onclick function` but there is another one in the `if statement`that i want to get it working.

Comment: @CaliburVictorious I see that now, you might want to have them print different messages for the sake of clarity while testing

Comment: @CaliburVictorious See my edited answer. is that what you need? (still weird though)

Comment: Well, That is working pretty fine, May i ask another thing? in my ajax request `$.get('page.php', {
x: x,
y: y
})`
the data part, I can't use this method in it, correct? Like, If status is true then print `u: u`, Is there any possible method to do that?

Comment: Good it worked! Regarding your another question, what is that? :p In $.get, you can pass an object as second parameter as data for query string. This object { x: x, y: y } are referencing two other variables (called x and y). But what is your question?

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares I want to check if the button is clicked or not, If it is clicked, i add into `This object { x: x, y: y }` this addition `u: u`, So it becomes `This object {x: x, y: y, u: u}` but if the button isn't clicked, the object stays as it is with 2 variables.

Comment: You can first assign the object with x and y only to a variable: `var obj = {x :x, y: y}`, and, then, check the status and add a new attribute if necessary: `if (status === 'active') obj.u = u`. Then you send this obj: `$.get('page.php', obj)`

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares Oh, I feel like my mind became really flat not being able to think about using variables for that, You really saved my day, sir. Thank you.